# Failed to set remote video description send parameters on Safari, But it woking fine in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: safari, webrtc, sdp

Here is sdpOffer:

```
v=0
o=- 2579350455277549780 1610962064 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=-
t=0 0
a=fingerprint:sha-256 04:9B:37:B3:32:6B:FB:23:C0:D6:19:EB:61:85:B6:7F:EB:3A:19:44:DB:C1:5B:B4:B0:15:7A:49:38:46:18:00
a=group:BUNDLE 0 1
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:0
a=ice-ufrag:uYIozschzbybzcjH
a=ice-pwd:xlXliBrswRNYGwKJMWSCHSaGwTQPjHju
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42001f
a=ssrc:3956969441 cname:xYppXcDkmOafnTrm
a=ssrc:3956969441 msid:xYppXcDkmOafnTrm FUhSMHFRpLUHkYer
a=ssrc:3956969441 mslabel:xYppXcDkmOafnTrm
a=ssrc:3956969441 label:FUhSMHFRpLUHkYer
a=msid:xYppXcDkmOafnTrm FUhSMHFRpLUHkYer
a=sendrecv
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 97 98
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:1
a=ice-ufrag:uYIozschzbybzcjH
a=ice-pwd:xlXliBrswRNYGwKJMWSCHSaGwTQPjHju
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:97 opus/8000/2
a=fmtp:97 ptime=10;minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:98 opus/48000/2
a=fmtp:98 ptime=10;minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=ssrc:513548820 cname:bRhpvRcAVgBCowya
a=ssrc:513548820 msid:bRhpvRcAVgBCowya XmNrnGRbNleCMODF
a=ssrc:513548820 mslabel:bRhpvRcAVgBCowya
a=ssrc:513548820 label:XmNrnGRbNleCMODF
a=msid:bRhpvRcAVgBCowya XmNrnGRbNleCMODF
a=sendrecv
```

I don't know why it has broken on Safari.

I got the following error when I called setRemoteDescription only on Safari browser **BUT it works fine on other browsers**.

```
Unhandled Promise Rejection: InvalidAccessError: Failed to set remote offer sdp: Failed to set remote video description send parameters.
```

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with how Safari blocks ICE candidates. To enable them, follow these steps:

```
In the upper menu:
(1) Safari > Preferences > Advanced > “Show Develop menu in menu bar.” - Shows the "Develop" option in the menu bar.
(2) Develop > WebRTC > “Disable ICE Candidate restrictions” - Disables ICE Candidates restrictions
```

These enable ICE candidates and should get your app working on Safari.

Comment: Oh! it works! thankyou. but I have a new problem.
the video is very lagging

Comment: @EarnAsdsa a video lagging doesn't have anything to do with Safari ICE candidates. If you are encountering trouble, please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and if this answer solved your problem, please click the green check mark next to the top of the post to show the community that this fixed your problem. Thanks!

Comment: still not working on device MacBook Pro 2019, OS: macOS BigSur 11.0.1, Safari Version 14.0.1 (16610.2.11.51.8)